# Can't get Responsive Img jQuery plugin to work

Tags: jquery

This will be simple for someone but I'm scarcely even a beginner at JavaScript; (I have tried Googling this)
I'm trying to get Responsive Img from http://responsiveimg.com/ to work.  The code below always loads the full sized test image which is 7.8MB both in the desktop and mobile phone browsers.  I see no new smaller images created as I would expect in the folder either.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="js/responsiveImg.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
{
    $("#img1").responsiveImg();
}
</script>

<title>Test Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test of responsive images program.  #6</h1>

  <div style="width:100%;">
      <img id="img1" src="IMG_0176.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" alt="BIG IMAGE">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

the test.html document, the image and the js folder are all in the same directory, a subdirectory of my /public_html/
I suspect I'm not entering $("#img1").responsiveImg(); correctly.

Comment: Check your console for errors. You have syntax errors inside your `<script>` tags.. and did you include jQuery?

Comment: include jQuery script, wrap your $("#img1").responsiveImg(); in DOM ready handler

Comment: why are you using jQuery just use bootstrap and define class .img-responsive on the image tag and your done

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Did get console error due to not including jQuery. That's fixed. I have included changes recommended below about document ready function ( DOM ready handler I believe). But the huge 4000x3000 image still loads in the browser and is resized down to 1235x926. I have used bootstrap and .img-responsive in my site revamp on some banner images and logos, but my site is for a camera club and I was hoping to resize images on the fly rather than having to have multiple versions

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing jQuery correctly. You need to use the .ready() method, or the short version of it. Additionally you should probably have your script tag at the end of the document before the `<body>` tag close.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#img1").responsiveImg();
});
```

This all does seem like overkill though, you could much more easily just create a responsive image CSS class that applies width: 100% and height: auto to certain images without having to load jQuery at all.

CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```